# Notation for differential equation involving inverse functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I can not figure out how to write “find $f(x)$ such that $\frac{df}{dx}$ is equal to the inverse function of $f(x)$”, or $f^{-1}(x)$)

I am not looking for the answer to this problem, just how you would write it in notation with $y^\prime$ and such.

Comment: $y'=y^{-1}(x)$ same as f notation $f'=f^{-1}$

Comment: @Isham huh, didn’t know you could do that same thing with $y$s

Comment: Connor $y'$ is just $\frac {dy}{dx}$ like the $f$ notation you are given Then you also have the composition of functions $y'\circ y(x)=x$

Comment: @zwim: in what sense would this question be a duplicate of that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual notation is ambiguous, unfortunately. It is natural to write  $y'=y^{-1} $, but you would have to clarify you are talking about the inverse, since it is also natural to read  $y^{-1} $ as $1/y $. It is a little less ambiguous if you write  $y'(x)=y^{-1}(x) $.